# Get bindings created through the Excel JavaScript API for Office from an Excel file

Tags: .net, excel, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

It is possible to create 'bindings' in an Excel file using the JavaScript API for Office. This allows Excel add-ins to 'name' parts of the data for later access. These bindings survive if the user renames elements, or moves them between worksheets.

[Bindings in the JavaScript API for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp160953.aspx#O15APIOverview_WorkingWithBindings)

Does anyone know of a way of getting the bindings out of a saved Excel file, when running outside the context of an Office add-in? Ideally a .NET library.

I've looked at Aspose Cells, Synfusion XlsIO, Closed XML and EPPPlus, which don't seem to support this. The Open Office XML SDK may support it, but it's very low-level and I'm not sure how to get at the bindings.

Any hints much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the document is stored on OneDrive or SharePoint you could access the Bindings Collection (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/ExcelJs_1.2_OpenSpec/excel/resources/bindingcollection.md) via the Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/) via REST.

Comment: Thanks very much Philip. In this case the documents are indeed in OneDrive - I didn't realise bindings were exposed through the graph API.

Answer (score 2):

In case the O365 solution Philip suggests isn't possible for your users, you can write any custom server-side code to get Bindings information. Bindings are part of the Open XML specification. The complete documentation is on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh695336(v=office.12).aspx or [in PDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijt97HwNzLAhUY0GMKHZjiC9cQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FD%2F3%2F3%2FD334A189-E51B-47FF-B0E8-C0479AFB0E3C%2F%5BMS-OWEXML%5D.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGjNAN2DfE0eY2XcIomNRGF_8nPKw&sig2=udc3y9HJkXtWDi0i1D076Q&bvm=bv.117868183,d.cGc). Searching for "bindings" should show you all the places they appear in the xlsx file format.

The companies you've mentioned may or may not have integrated with the Bindings feature or add-ins, but until they do you could build the integration yourself.

-Michael (PM on Office add-ins)

Comment: thanks Michael, that should point me in the right direction if I do delve into the xlsx file format.